# Segmentation fault when I create a little too big array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I have a C++ object in some part of my code like this:

```
class Object

{
public : 
float a, b, c;
}
```

When I create a 2 dimensional array like this, it works fine :

```
Object myArray [500][500];
```

When I make it like this, I get segmentation fault :

```
Object myArray [1000][1000];
```

What causes that segmentation fault, how can I get rid of it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a huge array, you need to make it global. Local variables have a size limit. Another solution is to allocate the array dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

Stack has a limited size, usually 1 to 10 MB on a modern machine. You array takes at least 16 MB.

The best case for this would be to allocate the array on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have exceeded the stack size so you either need to use dynamic arrays(hence heap) or increase the stack size in the compiler settings.